# Можно ли при запросе в node js с помощью модуля jsdom удалять добавлять элементы на html страничке

Tags: node.js, html

вот примерно накидал такой код:

```
var fs=require("fs");
var path=require("path");
var path=require("path");
var url=require("url");

var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom, 
myWindow = jsdom.parentWindow;
//$ = require('jquery').create(),
//jQuery = require('jquery').create(myWindow);

var server=require("http").createServer(function(req, res) {
var file_name=path.join(process.cwd(),"/jQuery/html/simple.html"),
    pathname=url.parse(req.url).pathname;
switch(pathname){
    case "/simple.html":
    path.exists(file_name,function(exists) {
        console.log(exists);
        fs.readFile(file_name,"utf8",function(err,data){

            jsdom.env({
                html:data,
                scripts:["http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"],
                done:function(err,window){
                    var $ = window.$;
                    $("#world").append("text");
                    $('body').append("<div class='testing'>Hello World</div>");               
                }
            });
                res.writeHead(200,{"Content-type":"text/html"});
                res.write(data,"utf8");
                res.end();
        });
    });
    break; 
    default:
        res.writeHead(200,{"Content-type":"text/plain"});
        res.write("hello");
        res.end();
    break;
}
```

});

Answer (score 2):

Можно:

```
jsdom.env({
  html:data,
  scripts:["http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"],
  done:function(err,window){
    var $ = window.$;
    $("#world").append("text");
    $('body').append("<div class='testing'>Hello World</div>");               
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-type":"text/html"});
    res.write(window.document.innerHTML,"utf8");
    res.end();                
  }
});
```

Правда на странице будут ваши дополнительные скрипты...